# jQuery Callback function won't take name of function(), must have an anonymous function

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

This works:

```
$("#formbottom").slideUp(speed,'swing',function(){
    openSubmitting();
});
```

This doesn't:

```
$("#formbottom").slideUp(speed,'swing',
    openSubmitting()
);
```

When you have a callback, do you always have to have an anonymous function in there? Can't you just put the function you want to call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`openSubmitting()` calls your function. You don't want the result of your function. You want your *actual* function, which is why you write `function() {...}` instead of `(function() {...})()`.

Since you want to pass a reference to your function, remove those parentheses:

```
$("#formbottom").slideUp(speed,'swing',
    openSubmitting
);
```

Comment: Ahh... yes, thanks.  Works without quotes, for future searchers.  I guess that's because js is considering openSubmitting as like a variable name, not a string like php: call_user_func('function').


If anyone has a link to eg 'jQuery Eye for the Php Guy'... lol, that would be helpful!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `jQuery("#formbottom").slideUp(speed,'swing',openSubmitting);`?

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer, Blender gets the check for the good explanation though.

Comment: It's alright, I don't mind actually. Just want to help :) Besides Blender deserves it because he explained it well.